# Network | Math: Smoothly lerp between inconsistent intervals

Tags: c#, math, networking, unity-game-engine, physics

So i'm working on a 1v1 2D game (using rigidbody physics + forces to jump/move), i send position+velocity data once every 0.05 seconds IF the distance between the last sent position and the current position is larger than a set amount.

So data arrives at inconsistent intervals and lerping causes a jittering motion. Is there anyone with a large enough brain to help me figure out how to smoothly lerp the position of the opponent that's received at inconsistent intervals? (e.g. intervals of: 0.06, 0.13, 0.83, 1.64, 0.67 etc)

Currently the smoothest method i've tried is to just feed in the opponent velocity, however the actual positions become out-of-sync over time.

It needs to feel like you're playing locally, as in no jittering/hiccups (even though position is slightly behind actual position due to network delay).

So to summarise, movement is entirely physics based (so the 2 characters on screen always move in an arc) so the problem is how do i incorporate both physics to move the opponent in an arc as well as correcting positional discrepancies? Or is this overcomplicating the matter?

I'm using C# but an explanation of the logic for the solution would be good enough!

Comment: Have you verified that your problem is related with irregular updates? Have you tried to set your threshold to 0 so your character is updated on any movement? Have you tried to update your character even if it doesn't move?

Comment: I've tried updating as often as possible but because movement relies on physics, the characters move in an arc, which is hard to fake without calculus, so i'm currently feeding it velocity and letting the physics work its magic, but because the data is slightly old, sometimes the local player will move their character in the path of the opponent character and alter the opponent character's position, and seeing as i don't manually move the opponent player's position, it becomes out of sync/position.

Comment: my point was to make sure that you understand your problem correctly, and tbh it doesn't look your biggest problem is irregular updates. 1v1 game with low network traffic = you can update as often as you wish, the question is what to update and how to process it